# Running Sails js in cloud-9 ide

Tags: sails.js, cloud9-ide

How can I run Sails.js in cloud-9 ide. The problem I have is when i say

sails lift

it creates a instance of localhost:8080 to run, but I have trouble accessing it from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On cloud 9 you need to go to the dynamic domain issued for your workspace. Which is usually

```
https://<WORK SPACE NAME>-c9-<YOUR USER NAME>.c9.io/
```

You can check this out by performing a Sails Lift, then click `Preview` - > `Preview with webserver`

If your sails.js is setup as follows, then it will be running on port 80, because cloud nine will specify a port.

```
port: process.env.PORT || XXXX,
```

If instead you directly specify, your port, then it will be set to `XXXX`

```
port: XXXX,
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure sails to use the IP and port as specified in the Cloud9 environment variables `$IP` and `$PORT`.

Just change your `config/env/development.js` to look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  port: process.env.PORT,
  host: process.env.IP
};
```

Then you can run it with `sails lift` from the terminal. In order to open the app just click `Preview -> Preview with web server` in the toolbar or navigate to:

```
https://<WORK SPACE NAME>-c9-<YOUR USER NAME>.c9.io/
```